# Show that $\ln(1/1-x) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{n}$ for $-1<x<1$

Tags: power-series

> Show that $\ln(1/1-x) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{n}$ for $-1<x<1$ using the power series $\frac{1}{1-x} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} x^n$

I did this using term by term integration

$\int \frac{1}{1-x} dx = (-1) \ln (1-x) + C = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}$

LHS: $\ln (1) - \ln (1-x) = \ln \frac{1}{1-x} + C$

What do I have to do with the right hand side of the equation? And afterwards, what is the reason for substituting $x=0$ to find the value of $C$ ? Where did the $x=0$ came from?

Comment: $\ln(1/1-x)$ should be written $\ln(1/(1-x))$ with parentheses.

Comment: If you have an equation which is true for any value of x, then you can substitute in any value that you like. So if it's useful to set $x=0$ then you are free to do so.

Comment: Note that $\ln (a^{-1})= -\ln a$.

Answer (score 3):

You are on the right track. For $ |x|<1$ let

$$f(x)= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{n}.$$

Then

$$f'(x)= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}x^{n-1}= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^{n}= \frac{1}{1-x}.$$

Hence

$$f(x)= - \ln (1-x)+c.$$

With $x=0$ we see that $c=0.$

Therefore

$$f(x)= - \ln (1-x)= \ln (1)-\ln (1-x)= \ln ( \frac{1}{1-x}).$$